# Why is the length of side $a$ of this triangle equal to $h \cdot A_n$?

Tags: geometry

I have a right-angled triangle:

[image]

I am told that $b$ has length $h$ and $c$ has slope $A_n$. The lecturer then concludes that $a$ has length $h \cdot A_n$.

I don't understand why this is true, so I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain it.

Comment: The slope is the ratio of the sides (i.e. slope = height/base). Just multiply through by the length of the base on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the hypotenuse by definition is:
$$ (\text{slope}) = \frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \frac{-a}{b} $$
So
$$ a = -(\text{slope}) \cdot b = -A_n \cdot h $$

Your lecturer either meant to say that $A_n$ is the magnitude of the slope, or forgot the negative sign denoting that the slope is downwards as we move to the right, as is the defined convention.